# "gem.add_dependency" for another local gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am creating a gem, which has a dependency on another published gem.
In **my_gem.gemspec**, I have added the dependency to the other gem:

`gem.add_dependency              "other_gem", "~> 1.0.0"`

Now, I found a feature that can be tweaked in **other_gem**, so I forked the repository, made my changes and committed it to the fork (It has not been pulled into the original repository).

My question is how do I tell **my_gem** to lookup **other_gem** locally? The below code snippet is not valid, as `:path` is not an option in `add_dependency` call, as mentioned in [Gem Specification Reference](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/):

`gem.add_dependency              "other_gem", "~> 1.0.0", :path => '/path/to/local/other_gem`

Comment: This post clarified a lot of my questions: http://yehudakatz.com/2010/12/16/clarifying-the-roles-of-the-gemspec-and-gemfile/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locally it's much easier: while you're doing development, you can include:

```
gem "other_gem", :path => '/path/to/local/other_gem'
```

or

```
gem "other_gem", :git => "git@github.com:/your_github/other_gem.git"
```

in your gemfile, as this should override the gemspec

Comment: Nope, :git options falls as well. If I try to include the local other_gem in my Gemfile, gem fails with message:       
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "other_gem":
  In Gemfile:
    my_gem (>= 0) ruby depends on
      other_gem (~> 1.0.0) ruby

Comment: Did you change the name or version of the other_gem? Try removing the version of the other gem

Comment: Sorry. There was a mismatch between versions of gem as available on RubyGems and on its Github master branch. After correction, the approach works. I could follow the same approach in production as well, but the project will then get locked to the forked repository as a side-effect, which is not desirable. Isn't there an option to link just the gem to a forked or local repository?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you're asking: you said that getting locked to the forked repository was bad, then asked if it was possible to link to a forked repository?

Comment: Also have you considered coding it to actively override the other files, i.e http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736451/override-a-method-inside-a-gem-from-another-gem

Comment: My comment was about linking my "rails projects" to a forked repository, vs. linking "my_gem" to a forked reponsitory. The other link seems interesting; will check it out and revert back.

Comment: Accepted, after your edit to locate the dependency in the gemfile, and override the gemspec.

Answer (score 0):

Locally it is not likely possible to give path to the gem dependency because if you are doing so that means you are imposing a restriction to the self made gem that it is depending locally to any other gem.

This is not desirable as when you will upload it, this will not work. So the solution is to add remote dependency in your own plugin's gemspec.

See my SO post for the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678957/how-to-add-dependency-of-a-local-gem-to-a-rails-plugin-engine-in-gemspec-file/13683662#13683662).

Comment: A small difference between my requirement and your post is that I want "my_plugin" to consider 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.pre2.patch', which is a forked repository of will_paginate and is local.

Answer (score 0):

I would create and install a new `other_gem`-version, e.g. '1.0.0.Subash_fix' and use it as

```
gem.add_dependency "other_gem", "= 1.0.0.Subash_fix"
```

When there is a new official version of the gem with your patch you switch back to the official one:

```
gem.add_dependency "other_gem", "~> 1.0.1"
```

Comment: Does this mean I will have to add other_gem.1.0.0.Subash_fix to rubygems.org? How will my_gem's bundle find this patched gem?

Comment: Normally you have no authorization for rubygems.org. Your original plan was to use a local path, so it's only on your computer. You can install the gem from a local source: `gem install other_gem.1.0.0.Subash_fix.gem --local`. Then it is available. If you want to give the gem to other persons, they also need your patched version of other_gem.

Comment: Correction: My idea works with require, but you already need it in the gemspec of your gem. Give me some time to think about it, but perhaps I will delete the answer if it is a blind alley.