# Making a change to mysql2_adapter.rb in activerecord gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to change `mysql2_adapter.rb` located in `/home/jimcgh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@myproject/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters`.

I want to redefine the connect method as follows

```
def connect
        @connection = Mysql2::Client.new(@config)
        @connection.options(Mysql::OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, 1) #Im adding this line
        configure_connection
end
```

If i just make this change, will it reflect in my rails app ?. Is there a better way to do this change?

Please Help
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

the best thing to do is fork the github repository, then commit the changes.

then, on your gem file reference it like this:

```
gem 'activerecord', :git => '##New git Repo##'
```

this way you wont have problems in production afterwards

Another solution is try to override the gem method on your application, here is another SO question on the topic:

[Overriding a module method from a gem in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580314/overriding-a-module-method-from-a-gem-in-rails)