# How to override a module method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module

I have a module that is included in a model. In this module, there is a `foo` method that I would like to override without modifying the existing model and module code.

My idea was to create a file `/lib/my_module_extend.rb`.
I don't know how to override the method in question because it's not like overriding a method in a class. I usually do:

```
module MyOriginalClassExtend
  ...
end

MyOriginalClass.class_eval do
  prepend(MyOriginalClassExtend)
end
```

but `class_eval` is not possible for a module. Do you have any idea?

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580314/overriding-a-module-method-from-a-gem-in-rails

Comment: Why not do `class MyOriginalClass; prepend MyOriginalClassExtend; end`?

Comment: @sawa this would be a possibility but I can't edit the file `MyOriginalClass `. Moreover this isn't the only class the module is included in

Comment: @Orsay: you don't need to edit that file. Write this in another file. It's called "open classes" (and modules, for that matter)

Comment: @sawa ok so I had to do it for all the files which include this module ? There are a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the same approach as for `open class` in ruby. You could just write an extension file in config/initializers and the method will be overridden when the application is loaded.

The below one could be more useful for anyone using Mongoid as the ORM for their application.

I created a extension file for [`Mongoid::Document`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongoid/current/) module as follows `config/initializers/mongoid_document_ext.rb`

```
module Mongoid
  module Document
    def as_json(options={})
      hs = super(options)
      hs["id"] = hs.delete("_id").to_s rescue nil 
      hs
    end
  end
end
```

This [monkey patching](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/monkey-patching-in-ruby/) worked pretty well for me!