# Capistrano getting commandline options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby, capistrano

Is there a way to get the command line option when executing the command task?

for eg.

```
cap staging namespace:task -z target_host
```

I'll try command-line arguments(ARGV) but length is only 2 that's for ["staging", "namespace:task"] I want to get -z (--HOST option).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your version of Capistrano.

In the case you're using the version 3, here is blog article explaining it: https://jtway.co/capistrano-3-passing-parameters-to-your-task-e22cc9f659c3.

Basically you pass arguments like you would do with rake tasks, so passing them between brackets (`[]`):

```sh
cap staging mynamespace:mytask[argument1,argument2]
```

Then in your task, you can catch them like so:

```rb
namespace : mynamespace do
  desc 'Description of my task here'
  task :mytask do |task, args|
    puts "Arguments: #{args.inspect}"
  end
end
```

In your example you would have to execute Capistrano that way:

```
cap staging namespace:task[target_host]
```

First argument would be the target hostname.

Comment: Thank you for your response sir, how about cap command options? 
i need to get this -z, --hosts HOSTS

Comment: You cannot use flags with Capistrano, you must pass then as arguments. I'm updating my answer in order to cover your example.

Answer (score 0):

Reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21446021/12359143
https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/configuration/host_filter.rb

```
Capistrano::Configuration::HostFilter.class_eval do

  def filter(servers)
    Array(servers).select { |s| @rex.match s.to_s }
  end

end
```